# HTML5 audio element in IE 10+ throwing "Invalid Source" for ShoutCAST mp3 stream

Tags: html, internet-explorer, audio-streaming, html5-audio, shoutcast

HTML example:

```
<audio src="http://subfocus.fm:8000/stream2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls></audio>
```

Confirmed to be working fine in Internet Explorer 9 and the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome on Windows 7. Since version 10, Internet Explorer returns "Invalid Source". Live example: http://subfocus.fm. Any known workarounds out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer 10 (and a few other browsers, including specific versions of Firefox) can't handle responses from SHOUTcast because the response status line is invalid.  Instead of something normal like `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`, SHOUTcast returns:

```
ICY 200 OK
```

The standard solution is to not use SHOUTcast, or proxy requests to your SHOUTcast server with other software.  Icecast is one of many options.

Comment: If you're interested, I'm doing some free hosting at the moment for those willing to use a test server.  Shoot me an e-mail at brad@audiopump.co for details.  I can relay your existing stream.